# C: 'const' qualifier meaning in parameter list with typedef usage

Tags: c, constants

How does the resolution of a parameter list work when a typedef and additional qualifier are used? Does it work like a textual replacement, similar to a #define?

Example:

```
typedef struct Parameters_t * Parameters_pot;
f(const Parameters_pot pars) 
f(Parameters_pot const pars)
```

Does the 'const' qualifier in the parameter list in both function delarations relate to the data type, meaning the pointer is pointing to a constant structure?
Or does the position of the 'const' matter and in the first function declaration the 'const' means that the structure object is constant and in the second declaration it means that the pointer is constant?

Comment: Why don't you ask the compiler? Make a small example and try to write the structure and pointer in both cases.

Comment: The standard seems somewhat vague about this, I would struggle to find a relevant quote from there. The compiler seems like a safer bet.

Comment: @teapot418 Thx for your answer. I'm concerned about different compilers having different interpretations. Where could I look for an explanation from the standard?

Comment: @Daniel This is some seriously hard part of the standard to read. C17 6.7.8 specifies typedef but that one only leads you on to 6.7.6. From where you won't understand much unless you dig into the the listed formal syntax about "direct declarators" and "type qualifier lists" and then sub chapter 6.7.6.1 pointer declarators.

Comment: I feel position matters but not sure.

Comment: @Lunding I think you mean "direct-abstract-declaratoropt [ type-qualifier-list static assignment-expression ]" from chapter 6.7.6. I'm not sure how to read this.

Comment: If you're worried about portability, take your toy example over to https://godbolt.org/ and go through all the compilers available there.

Comment: @teapot418 godbolt.org appears to miss a popular compiler: [CCS](https://www.ccsinfo.com/compilers.php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not text replacement. And that's exactly why hiding pointers or arrays behind a `typedef` is considered very bad practice. Both examples here are equivalent to:

`f(struct Parameters_t * const pars)`

Only since it was requested, here's an attempt at explaining the formal language lawyering:

C17 6.7.8 states that a typedef has the form as `typedef T type_ident;` where `type_ident` is a type name "with the type specified by the declaration
specifiers in `T`". Specifiers plural. To understand this we have to step back to 6.7 and 6.7.6 regarding "declarators" and "declaration-specifiers".

6.7.6 says that every declaration can be said to consist of `T D1` where `T` is the declaration specifiers and `D1` the declarator.

- A "declaration-specifier" is everything you may write in front of the identifier in a declaration, including storage class specifiers (`static` etc) and type qualifiers (`const` etc) and of course also type specifiers (`int` etc). Several of these may optionally exist in the same declaration.

  Except for storage class specifiers, which as a special case can never be combined with each other (6.7.1). And as it happens, `typedef` counts as a storage class specifier, so we can't have things like `static` inside a `typedef`.
- A "declarator" contains the identifier as well as array notation etc. It may optionally contain a `*` for pointers. The important part here is that `*` belongs to the declarator.

  The formal syntax (6.7.6) goes as:

  > *declarator:*
  > *pointer<sub>opt</sub> direct-declarator*
  > ...
  > *pointer:*
  > `*` *type-qualifier-list<sub>opt</sub>*

Going back to `typedef T type_ident;`, then everything that is `T` belongs to the type, including any qualifiers, pointer syntax, array syntax etc that was used.

Thus should we write something like `const T`, then `const` is applied to the whole type `T`. Now if we had 'T' as for example `const int*` "a pointer to const int" then `const T` will therefore create a `const int* const`, "a const pointer to const int".

If `T` was a function, then it will attempt to declare a "const function" which is invalid. And so on.

---

So for your example `typedef struct Parameters_t * Parameters_pot;`, the `const` is applied to the type `struct Parameters_t *`.

Therefore `f(const Parameters_pot pars)` is equivalent to `f(struct Parameters_t * const pars)`.

`f(Parameters_pot const pars)` also has the same equivalent meaning, for the same reason as `int const` and `const int` are equivalent - the order in which declaration specifiers may appear isn't specified most of the time.

Answer (score -3):

Parameters_pot is a alias of struct Parameters_t *.So you example is like this:

```
f(const struct Parameters_t * pars) the pointer is pointing to a constant structure.
f(struct Parameters_t * const pars) the pointer is constant.
```

Comment: This is what I did expect. But there are also other opinions, saying that the 'const' is always an attribut of the pointer, even if it is placed on the imaginary right side of the '*'. The standard must describe somewhere how the typedefs are resolved (textual or somehow else).

Comment: @Daniel This example correctly places the const at the right side and there is nothing "imaginary" about it.

Comment: Actually the first line of this answer `const struct Parameters_t * pars` is wrong.

Comment: @Daniel The Parameters_pot is an alias you define through typedef, which is a pointer to the Parameters_t structure. If const precedes it, then the point of this pointer is constant. If const follows it, then the pointer itself is constant. Depends if const comes before or after "*".

Comment: @feiniks I have now tested both versions with GCC: The const is always applied to the pointer. This means the content of the variable that the pointer points to can always be changed and the pointer itself can never be changed.